# Where did yum put boost?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, boost

I installed `boost.x86_64` on my Linux system:

```
$ sudo yum install boost.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: mirror.uoregon.edu
 * updates: mirror.uoregon.edu
Setting up Install Process
Package boost-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But when I looked for the boost files, I couldn't find them:

```
$ sudo repoquery --list boost-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
$
```

This is a bit strange, as I have boost and several of its dependencies installed:

```
$ sudo rpm -qa | grep boost
boost-signals-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-graph-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-program-options-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-system-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-date-time-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-wave-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-serialization-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-thread-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-test-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-python-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-regex-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-random-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-filesystem-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
boost-iostreams-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64
```

Is there another destination for files that `repoquery` cannot find?

The reason I ask is that I have a boost dependency in a software tool I am trying to compile, and it cannot locate the boost installation (and neither can `repoquery`, apparently).

Thanks for any suggestions or tips.

**EDIT**

I overlooked installing the headers, as well:

```
$ sudo yum install boost-devel.x86_64
```

Once I did this, I could find those headers:

```
$ repoquery --list boost-devel.x86_64
/usr/include/boost
/usr/include/boost/accumulators
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators_fwd.hpp
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework
/usr/include/boost/accumulators/framework/accumulator_base.hpp
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repoquery` is a tool is a tool to query yum repository, not the installed packages.

To find the files provided by your package you need : `rpm -ql boost-1.44.0-8.fc14.x86_64`

Comment: for clarity, that's an L after the Q (it looks like a 1 in many fonts)

Answer (score 8):

`locate boost`

Thought I'd throw in the `locate` command.  I seem to get better results with it personally.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, why the downvote?  'locate libboost' is exactly what I needed. +1.